# Cannot insert BLOB data into table

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am trying to store an image in a blob column. I created the table,  job_resumes2, using the following code:

```
create table job_resumes2(
resume_id number,
first_name varchar2(25),
last_name varchar2(25),
profile_picture blob);
```

I then created a directory:

```
create directory myimages as 'C:\MYIMAGES';
```

I then executed the following procedure to populate the table, but I get an error when executing it:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  SRC bfile := bfilename('MYIMAGES','x.jpg');
  3  dest blob;
  4  begin
  5  insert into job_resumes2 values(1,'John','M',empty_blob())
  6  returning profile_picture into dest;
  7  dbms_lob.open(src,dbms_lob.lob_readonly);
  8  dbms_lob.loadfromfile(dest,src,dbms_lob.getlength(src));
  9  dbms_lob.close(src);
 10  commit;
 11  end;
 12  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
The data is invalid.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1031
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

I have ensured that the directory and the file, x.jpg, exist.
What is the problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: provide the required access privileges GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY myimages TO USERNAME then try once.

Comment: I can't grant this privilege to myself. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the database installed? Is it on your computer? Because, directory has to reside on the database server (or be accessible to it - if it is elsewhere, use UNC to create it). "C:\temp" looks like it is your own PC, so - it might not work.

As of privileges: directory (as an Oracle object) is owned by SYS, and SYS has to grant privileges to user(s) that will be using it, such as

```
grant read, write on directory myimages to jtruant;
```

**[EDIT: here's a working example]**

This is my directory:

```
SQL> select directory_name from all_directories;

DIRECTORY_NAME
------------------------------
EXT_DIR
```

Creating a table:

```
SQL> create table job_resumes2
  2    (resume_id       number,
  3     first_name      varchar2(25),
  4     last_name       varchar2(25),
  5     profile_picture blob);

Table created.
```

Running a procedure:

```
SQL> declare
  2    src_lob  bfile := bfilename('EXT_DIR', 'robco.jpg');
  3    dest_lob blob;
  4  begin
  5    insert into job_resumes2
  6      (resume_id, first_name, last_name, profile_picture)
  7    values
  8      (1, 'John', 'M', empty_blob())
  9      returning profile_picture into dest_lob;
 10
 11    dbms_lob.open(src_lob, dbms_lob.lob_readonly);
 12    dbms_lob.loadfromfile( dest_lob => dest_lob,
 13                           src_lob  => src_lob,
 14                           amount   => dbms_lob.getlength(src_lob) );
 15    dbms_lob.close(src_lob);
 16
 17    commit;
 18  end;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Is there anything there?

```
SQL> select dbms_lob.getlength(profile_picture) from job_resumes2;

DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(PROFILE_PICTURE)
-----------------------------------
                               6427

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK. Try to follow my steps and see what happens.

Comment: The database is installed on my computer. I have created another user and granted read and write on the directory to them. Still, the PL/SQL block will not execute and gives me the same error message.

Comment: I edited my message by adding an example. Have a look.